# What is this large engine doing on a B52?

Tags: jet-engine, multi-engine, b-52

In [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/eTUFOvgBxS0), discussing plans to use the 747 as an aircraft carrier, there is a brief sequence starting at 4 min 14 s, showing images of a B52:

[image: B52 from underneath]

[image: B52 from side]

What is the explanation for the very different inboard engine pod on the starboard wing? There is a current call for proposals to re-engine the B52 with eight modern engines. Was this an earlier test of moving to four larger engines instead?

Comment: Wikipedia mentions that retrofitting the engines was considered in the 1970s and again in the 1980s, but I can't find a quotation that indicates it was physically tested.

Comment: You know, these days you could surely have a sort of "airborne drone aircraft carrier" - carrying a few dozen "big drones", say.  Unreal!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[Testbed Aircraft Cameos](http://www.memagazinedigital.org/memagazine/september_2019/MobilePagedArticle.action?articleId=1516909#articleId1516909)

> As a young engineer in the 1960s at Pratt & Whitney Aircraft (now
>   UTC’s Pratt & Whitney) in East Hartford, Connecticut, I was involved
>   (along with many others) in the development of their 44,000 pound
>   thrust (lbt) JT9D turbojet, which powered the first Boeing 747 jumbo
>   jet aircraft[ Display footnote number: 2 ]. Because of its then
>   ground-breaking large fan diameter (new for the 1960s), P&WA had to
>   use a U.S. Air Force Boeing B-52 as a testbed. The Stratofortress,
>   with its high wing, allowed the JT9D to be mounted with adequate
>   ground clearance for takeoff and landing. In Figure 1, the P&WA
>   testbed aircraft is shown landing at the Windsor Locks, Bradley
>   International Airport, after a test flight, with a JT9D engine
>   replacing two TF-33 inboard engines on the right wing of the
>   eight-engined B-52.
>
> The B-52 continued as a P&WA testbed aircraft until 1981, even after
>   being damaged in its hangar by a violent tornado that raced through
>   Windsor Locks in 1979. Pratt & Whitney more recently used two Boeing
>   747SP aircraft for testbeds, to flight test their new geared fan jet
>   engines.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a definitive answer and image. The rest of that post is worth looking at too. Will leave this open for a further feedback  but presumably this will be the answer I accept.

Comment: Dammit, beaten by just minutes :) points to you good sir for quicker fingers.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know the ultimate fate of JB-52E? Since it's a -E and the only ones in service today are -H I would assume it was either scrapped or boneyarded, but would love to know for certain.

Comment: FTR, the JT9D is a turbofan, not turbojet.

Answer (score 22):

The plane in the pictures is [Boeing JB-52E](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Upcoming/Photos/igphoto/2000532428/) -test plane.

It used to test for instance the [General Electric TF-39](http://wikimapia.org/23210506/Boeing-JB-52E-55BW-Stratofortress) engines for the C-5 Galaxy as it was under development

Comment: Nice - extends the other answer by showing that this was a testbed for several engine types.